# Android Library: Handle async http requests internally?

Tags: android, android-library

I'm writing an Android library that makes http requests to a bunch of different services.  Currently, I have the http requests happening in an AsyncTask and calling back to an app supplied delegate with results in the onPostExecute method.  So, basically the developer invokes their desired method without worrying about creating an AsyncTask.

However, I'm starting to wonder if I should be making these calls asynchronously or leave the library completely synchronous and put the responsibility on the dev to put the method calls in AsyncTasks in their apps.  Is there a best practice about things like this?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience of being a part of several projects with wide APIs, in most cases where we decided to provide an asynchronous API, in the end, we had to either provide additional synchronous API or make the old asynchronous API obsolete with new synchronous API.

When I write an API, I try to avoid any assumption as for the end user.
I think you'll find the following interesting (or so I hope):
[How to Write Good API](http://lcsd05.cs.tamu.edu/slides/keynote.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be strict, put the asynchronous task in your library so the developers have no choice other than to do the request asynchronously (which is already done in your library).

But if you want to be more flexible, leave the decision to the developers whether they want to put it in asynchronous or not.

If I were you, I'll leave the decision to developers as the purpose of the library is to do the request and get the result, not how to do the request. This way, your library will fit in any developer's desire and not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a good idea to make the calls asynchronously in your library. To notify the calling `Activity` when the data is received you should define in your `Class` an abstract method that you call inside your class after the request and processing is complete. And then the user that uses your `Class` will have to implement that method, and that method will be called when the processing is complete. For example:

```
    public class ProcessingClass{
        private void processData(){
             //Async processing
             .....
             onProcessComplete();
        }
        public abstract void onProcessComplete(){

        }
    }
```

And then let's say inside your activity you can do something like this:

```
    private class MyProcessingClass extends ProcessingClass{
        @Override
        public void onProcessComplete(){
             //The task is complete...
             //Update UI or something like this...
        }
    }
```